# seo and php get variables

Tags: php, url, seo, blog

I'm building my own blogging system for my own website. If all I preload them using php get variables, will Google recognize and index them as different pages or do I need to do something in addition to get Google to recognize and index them separately?

i.e `page.php?blogId=00001&blogTitle=BlogTitle`

Comment: Google won't have any problem for that. Your blog readers, maybe.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Google will recognize and index them as different pages.

However, it will recognize it better if the address would be `/00001/BlogTitle/`

Comment: is it possible to do that in php without having to make the individual directories and files?

Comment: no, that's impossible with PHP. mod_rewrite or it's equivalents. htere are plenty answers on SO, just search for seo friendly urls

Comment: Should be possible with .htaccess and Apache.  I'm pretty sure you can do 'pretty links' with IIS as well.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: There's no need to rewrite URLs or use a fake directory structure. Google gets understands both kinds of URLs and even [recommends not creating fake static-looking URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html).

Answer (score 5):

Google will recognize and index them as different pages. But what you can do that will help is build a site map so that when a new blog is add it is also add to the site map. Makes it nice and easy for google to see.

Also you can use [googles webmasters tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/). This way you can see what google is seeing helps a lot.

Comment: Sitemaps are a great idea.  If you're already using PHP it should be pretty easy as well.  How to format: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Answer (score 3):

Use [HTACCESS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) to make your URLs search engine friendly.